# Error: "command line driver for internet explorer has stopped working " when trying to destroy the driver in selenium

Tags: iframe, selenium, webdriver, internet-explorer-10

When running automation tests with selenium, I have been getting this error routinely, but not always, after a test passes. After a pass, it tries to destroy the driver but stalls, and this is not acceptable when running many tests back to back. Seems to happen in tests that switch the iframe often, but I cannot figure out a solution. I tried switching to defaultcontent, which I saw as a fix somewhere else, and it does not work. I am running windows 7 and internet explorer 10, but the issue persists in XP Mode on IE 8 as well.

IE Driver 2.32.3.0

It fails when:

```
        if (driver != null)
        {
            Driver.Quit();
            driver = null;
        }
```

The issue also seems to happen after I use a foreach loop through a table that has 60+ rows. Perhaps it is just a memory issue.

I clicked debug on the error and got this in a new instance of visual studio:

Unhandled exception at 0x771a15de in IEDriverServer.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I added a little bit, it is a difficult issue to explain with code though.

Comment: Ok.  I looked up the issue...what version of IEDriver are you on?

Comment: Using IEDriver version 2.32.3.0

Comment: Use the `InternetExplorerService` class, to specify a logging level for the IEDriver, use the TRACE log level. Reproduce the problem, and check out it's logfile. Post it here.

Comment: According to this document: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4178 you need to be on 2.33

Comment: Turns out I did not understand the issue perfectly. I updated Selenium to 2.34 based on what I saw here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5836 - the issue no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CONFIRMED: The issue does not occur on IE driver 2.34

Comment: It does on 2.37 though =/

Comment: I've been having all kinds of new problems with 2.37, doesn't surprise me at all that this is occurring again. Very unfortunate when you're running a full regression.