# Command line server for the IE WebDriver has stopped working: Why this happening & How we can find a solution for this

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I come across this problem "command line server for the ie driver has stopped working" when execute my selenium batch tests on Internet explorer browser most of the times...
..... this seriously impact the test execution...Have seen many posts in web regarding this , but could not make out why this issue happens ,and how we can find a solution for this ...Please let me know if you knows any detail reading this ,
Many Thanks,
~Musaffir

Comment: Windows xp or 7? IE and IEdriverserver version?

Comment: IEdriverserver 64bit 2.33.0 version + IE8 +Windows 2008 server OS... i guess this prob happens on other env as well thats what i could read in various posts...

Comment: As per the answer for the question in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089725/error-command-line-driver-for-internet-explorer-has-stopped-working-when-try), you can upgrade to IE driver 2.34(or else you can download the latest 2.35 version) and check if the issue is still there.

Comment: Yep....am trying my luck with that already...wat am more interested is to know the reason that makes the IE webdriver stops working in middile of the tests....

Comment: Any difference with the 32bit version? What code are you using to create the IEDriver? Show us. Is there reproducible on another machine?

Comment: The issue is reproducible on IE 10, Windows 7, IEDriver 32 bit. I think its related to some memory issue.

Comment: @Traveller87 Any progress on the problem? I have the same

Comment: Download it from this site: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.0/ please refer to @banrieen's ans

Answer (score 1):

Cause of the error is that: IE11 with the IEDriverServer_x64_3.5.0 or latest version on windows 7 64bit or other system environment.

[image]

This error is not about the IE security setings or regedits, but because the IEDriverServer version is not compatible.

Please use the IEDriverServer_x64_3.0.0.

Download it from this site:

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.0/

Answer (score 1):

From IEDriverserver v3.5.0.0 changelog:

- To successfully use this version of the IE driver, you should be using
  version 3.5 or above of the language bindings. Those are the only versions
  of language bindings that will understand the payload required to be sent
  during the creation of a new session. Earlier versions of the language
  bindings are not guaranteed to be fully compatible with this release of
  the IE driver.

You should use the the 32 bit version of the driver because of this update in v2.47.0.1:

- Enabled fast failure for cookie manipulation in IE. The refactor of cookie
  handling for the IE driver introduces an incompatibility with the 64-bit IE
  driver and IE 10 and 11 running on 64-bit Windows. As is the case with
  sending keystrokes and creating screenshots, a Windows hook procedure is now
  used for getting and settingcookies in IE. That means that in IE 10 and 11
  on 64-bit Windows, where the content rendering process is still 32-bit, you
  **must** use the 32-bit IEDriverServer.exe in order to manipulate cookies.
  This commit will now cause exceptions to be thrown if you attempt to set
  or get cookies using the 64-bit driver against a 32-bit version of IE (or
  vice versa), but in particular, this will affect users who mistakenly try
  to use the 64-bit executable with IE 10 or 11 in 64-bit Windows.

You should download the v3.4.0 for Win 32 from here:
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0.zip

(Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG)