# Command line server for the IE driver has stopped working error while running selenium test cases

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm receiving an error prompt box while executing Selenium Test cases.

I'm using `IEDriver 2.46` and `Selenium 2.46`. I have searched few posts in Stack Overflow and there is not a  proper answer that I could use in my environment.

Is there any generic solution or a code change which might fix this issue? I'm using `IE 9 (64 bit, Win 7)`

I have refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292083/command-line-server-for-the-ie-webdriver-has-stopped-working-why-this-happening), but it is not work for me.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5848) some people managed to fix this problem by adding a new key in the registry.
The new key is located in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main", its name is "TabProcGrowth", and its value is "0".

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me, but maybe it will work for you.

[This site](http://blogs.technet.com/b/doxley/archive/2009/10/14/putting-iexplore-exe-on-a-diet.aspx) has further details on the specifics of this key and the actual impacts it may have.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that the javascript in the code is causing this error. In my case , I had written a script for click on an element (Given below)
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);

I got the error while executing this line of code. I commented this line and opted for selenium click. And voila the error is gone.

Please try commenting javascripts in the code if you have any and try running again.
link to the blog where I found this :
http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2014/12/windows-update-kb3025390-for-ie-11.html

Answer (score 0):

I get this error while clicking on an element in a particular page. I removed .click() to clicking element using Actions class in Java. It worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\{user}.m2\repository\webdriver\IEDriverServer\beta\Win32\IE.Driver.Beta and replace IEDriverServer.exe with new version it should work